# Need UK Visa from Europe for Indian Passport holders

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I am on Europe visit right now and need UK business visa to attend a conference. Is it possible to get UK visa from Barcelona.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply online from any location where there is a U.K. embassy or processing centre. https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/apply Attending a conference is a permitted activity for a Visitor Visa